# AMD proprietary driver doesn't let me see the temperature

Tags: drivers, ati, temperature

I had a problem with higher GPU temperature in Ubuntu than in Windows, so i tried installing the proprietary driver for AMD mobility radeon HD 5650. Now I can't see the temperature.

Does this mean that the sensor is unaccessible? Will my computer automatically shut down if the temperature goes above 100C ?

Note: I am using Psensor to see the temperatures

Comment: I hope my answer below will be helpful. Just out of interest: At what temperature does your GPU run now after installing the proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same graphics card and I've found that Psensor doesn't reliably work with the proprietary drivers. But there's another way you can check up on the GPU temperature. Open up a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> under Unity) and type in the following command:

```
aticonfig --odgt --odgc
```

It will show you both your current GPU temperature and information on its workload:

```
$ aticonfig --odgt --odgc

Default Adapter - AMD Radeon HD 6500M/5600/5700 Series
                  Sensor 0: Temperature - 54.00 C

Default Adapter - AMD Radeon HD 6500M/5600/5700 Series
                            Core (MHz)    Memory (MHz)
           Current Clocks :    400           800
             Current Peak :    550           800
  Configurable Peak Range : [450-550]     [800-800]
                 GPU load :    0%
```

On my system I have set up an alias for this command so that I can access it quickly if need be. To do so you can just edit the `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory:

```
gedit .bash_aliases
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
alias gpuinfo='aticonfig --odgt --odgc'
```

Save the file and restart the terminal. From now on you will be able to access you GPU temperature with the command `gpuinfo`.

Comment: the command retruns aticonfig: "No supported adapters detected". Also, i have an "unsupported hardware" watermark in the corner

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled the AMD support when you have compiled Psensor? The Psensor package in the Ubuntu repository did not enabled the AMD support during the compilation so you can only monitor the AMD GPU when you using the opensource driver.

See http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/doc/faq.html#S_ATIMonitoring.
Compilation instruction to enable the AMD support is available at: http://wpitchoune.net/svnpub/psensor/trunk/README in the section 'ATI/AMD GPU Support'